# SEDE Graph add column names as label for axis

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, data-explorer, graphs

This [graph result](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1202086#graph) shows number of post (y-axis) over the last months (x-axis).

The query result has this format

```
 MonthsAgo    |   TagName      |    NrOfPosts
 -------------|----------------|----------------
       -12    |   directus     |       5
       -12    |  orchardcore   |       9
       -12    |  serenity-pla  |       0
       -11    |   directus     |       2
       -11    |  orchardcore   |       12
```

It would be great if the axis would be labeled with the column names `NrOfPosts` on the y-axis and `MonthsAgo` on the x-axis [image: SEDE Graph Example].

Comment: Note that SEDE is open source ([GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer)), and the technologies used align with the ones you state you know in your profile.

Comment: It seems that [jquery.flot.js](https://githubusercontent.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Scripts/flot/) and [query.graph.js](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Scripts/) render the graph `response.graph = new DataExplorer.Graph(resultSet, '#graph');` From [flot docs](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md) i assume that `jquery.flot.axislabels.js`  takes care of `axisName`. How to pass columnName to `graph = $.plot(target, series, options);` is still unclear to me.